# Querying the button if the time past from exact time

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to enable my button when the time comes 12:00 PM, because that was the data in my database, but I forget to open my program in 12:00 PM? The time passed to 2:00 PM and the button still needs to maintain the enabled status.

What is the query for that vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy this scenario, you have to change your **time** to a **time range**. 
(Or just check if the current time equals or greater than the fixed time)

```
[12 PM - 3PM for example]
```

Whenever the applications is run, you have to initiate a method that will check the current time with your range. Based on it, you will enable or disable your button.

```
if(current time is in the given range)
    yourButton.Enabled = True
else
    yourButton.Enabled = False
```

So, it would not matter if you open your application at a later time.